# how to get the count of total comments posted for specific content type including deleted comments too?

Tags: views, comments

I want to get the total count of comments posted only for a specific content type including deleted to get the highest comment id no matter whether comment is been deleted. please help me or else suggest me other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can always dig around the database with a db query with something like:

```
$content_type = 'mycontenttype';
$query = db_select('comment', 'c');

$query->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = c.nid'); //JOIN node with comment
$query->fields('c', array('cid')); //SELECT the fields from comment
$query->condition('n.type', $content_type, '=');
$query->orderBy('c.cid', 'DESC'); //ORDER BY comment id

$num_comments = $query->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
$latest_comment_cid = $query->execute()->fetchField();
```

**EDIT**
In this example I assume you mean unpublished comments and not deleted. See Anil's answer if you want to track count of deleted comments as well.

Comment: Does this code give me the count of deleted comments too?

Comment: @D-pak it gives you the count of published and unpublished comments. See my Edit and Anil's answer for more information about deleted comments.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a custom module to achieve this... I am afraid there won't be any contributed module which will give you stats even if comment is deleted... Please find steps below to solve your use case..

- Create a custom module
- Implement [hook_schema](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) in .install file and create a table to track comment inserts so that even if a comment is deleted you have an entry of comment
- Implement [hook_comment_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_insert/7) in .module file to update above custom table you have created using hook_schema

---

```
function hook_comment_insert($comment) {
  // Reindex the node when comments are added.
  $node = node_load($comment->nid);
  if ($node->type == "YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE") {
     // Use db_insert to make an entry to track comments into your custom table 
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will do this, But will it give me that count as a field in views?

Comment: @D-pak You will have to write views plugin for the above scenario like you will have to expose your custom table to the views.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved. this issue was there because I had replaced text-area with text-box on comment form. I just did revert it and it worked. But I don't think that just replacing fields this issue occurs.